# Old horror movie with creatures eating all matter in the past

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I remember watching this as a child, it was very scary for me, I had nightmares. I think it's around 25-30 years old.

It's happening on an airport, there is some time traveling included I think, and then some huge round creatures with mouths full of scary teeth like saws appear and eat everything.

Comment: Was it live action? What do you mean in the title by _"eating all matter in the past"_?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The movie is called "The Langoliers" (1995)

Let's just say that the effects didn't age well.

It is [miniseries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Langoliers_(miniseries)), often shown as a single movie.

> During a red eye flight of a Lockheed L-1011 from Los Angeles
>   International Airport to Boston Logan International Airport, the plane
>   flies through a strange light, and most of the passengers and flight
>   crew disappear, leaving behind only personal artifacts. Only those
>   passengers who were asleep remain, and discover the predicament when
>   they wake. Pilot Brian Engle, deadheading on the flight, takes the
>   controls; unable to contact any other airport, he decides to land the
>   plane at Bangor International Airport because of its long runway.
>    Turns out they traveled into past and there are creatures living there
>   eating the past to make place for the future. Creatures called Langoliers.

See if it rings any bells here:

Image of the creatures here:

[image: langoliers, round creatures with huge teeth, eating the past]

Comment: Ah beat me to it and got a nice picture of the monsters +1

Comment: Delete your answer, then :)

Comment: Based on a Stephen King novella.

Answer (score 5):

#### [*The Langoliers*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112040/) (1995)

> On a red eye flight to Boston from LA 10 people wake up to a shock. All the passengers and crew have vanished. When they try to contact the ground they make no connections. They land the plane only to discover that things haven't changed. But its like the world is dead. No one is there, the air is still, sound doesn't echo, the food is tasteless. And a distant sound is heard coming closer. A race of monstrous beings bent on their destruction is heading for them, eating everything in sight.

You can see the trailer below: